# reference for operator algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-algebras

I am taking a course on operator algebra this semester. My instructor has suggested a reference "Kadinson and Ringrose." Are there any other good/standard references for this subject that I can look up?

Comment: Very useful: ["Operator Algebras:
Theory of C*-Algebras and von Neumann
Algebras"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=6b_T1j3Ib8oC&hl=fr&source=gbs_similarbooks), by Blackadar. Great, fairly exhaustive, up-to-date overview of definitions and known facts. Not a course, though, rather an encyclopedic account with some proofs here and there (not sure if he wants that, but the pdf is hosted on his webpage and can be googled).

Comment: Do you know the intended focus of the course? (e.g. $C^*$-algebras or von Neumann algebras? If K-theory is going to be covered, is it from the perspective of classification or noncommutative geometry?) In any case, Fillmore's "A User's Guide to Operator Algebras" makes good light reading on the subject.

Comment: @Michael This course will touch both $C^{\star}$ and von Neumann algebras. $K-$ theory will not be discussed though. Can you suggest some topics that should be included in a first course in Operator Algebra?

Comment: Fillmore touches on both $C^*$- and von Neumann algebras, good bedtime reading. I would endorse the Davidson and Blackadar books already suggested (although latter, like julien said, is not a textbook). Davidson is really great if you can go through it with someone knowledgeable providing a big picture perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The book by Kadison and Ringrose does not contain a number modern topics (irrational rotation algebras, Cuntz algebras, K-theory etc.). I have used the following books for my lectures:

*G.Murphy "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory"*

and the

*K.Davidson "$C^*$-algebras by example."*

A nice introduction to K-theory of $C^*$-algebras with prerequisites on $C^*$-algebras is

*N.E.Wegge-Olsen "K-theory and $C^*$-algebras. A friendly approach."*

On the other hand I find the book by Kadison and Ringrose much easier to read.

The classical monograph by Dixmier can be used as encyclopedia of basic $C^*$-algebra theory.

Comment: Hi! I even though this is an old post, I hope you can get to this question I have. I'm currently self-studying functional analysis, and by the end of August I will have finished the text *Functional Analysis; An Introduction* by Eidelman-Milman-Tsolomitis. I'm curious if after finishing this text, would I be able to read through the text *K-theory and $C^∗$-algebras. A friendly approach* by N.E.Wegge-Olsen? That is to say, under the assumption, the text by Eidelman-Milman-Tsolomitis is all I know, i.e. I don't know any algebraic geometry, category theory, etc.

Comment: Hi. I don't know the book by Eidelman-Milman-Tsolomitis. Important is to learn the basics of the operator theory: spectrum, compact operators, self-adjoint operators, spectral theorem for normal, unitary, self-adjoint operators etc. Then you have the prerequisites for any of these books.

Comment: Thank you. Everything you listed I have learned, and I'm about to begin on the section of book over algebras, which includes the Gelfand-Naimark theorem. I took a look through the text *K-theory and C∗-algebras. A friendly approach* by N.E.Wegge-Olsen, and I noticed the terminology uses category theory, modules, etc.. Do you think a background in algebra and some category is needed?