# Why is $\|P(A)\|^2 = \|P(A)^*P(A)\| = \|(\overline P P)(A)\|$ for $P(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n A^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space. Reed and Simon I, page 223, it says that for $P(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n A^n$ we have

$$
\|P(A)\|^2 = \|P(A)^*P(A)\| = \|(\overline P P)(A)\|
$$

Why do these two equalities hold? I'm not even sure I understand what is meant by the notation '$(\overline P P)(A)$'?

Comment: Are you familiar with the $C^*$-identity? Di you have othet results to use in conjunction with thid?

Comment: $P (A)$ seems to denote the power series in $A$. Is it self-adjoint?

Comment: @eurocoder Please see the first line on page 223 for the definition of $P(A)$ . The last part of Theorem VII.1 a) is used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a power series $P(x) =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ then $\overline{P}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a_n}x^n$ is the power series with complex conjugation applied to every coefficient.

The identity $\|T\|^2 = \|T^*T\|$ holds for any bounded map $T$, and is called the [$C^*$-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra).

Furthermore, $T \mapsto T^*$ is antilinear, [continous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474353/144766) and antimultiplicative so:

$$P(A)^* = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nA^n\right)^* = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a_n}(A^*)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a_n}A^n = \overline{P}(A)$$

If $P(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $Q(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ are two power series, then $$(PQ)(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_nb_{n-k}\right)x^n$$ is the product of $P$ and $Q$.

The equality $P(T)Q(T) = (PQ)(T)$ clearly holds for any bounded map $T$.

Putting this together:

$$\left\|P(A)\right\|^2 = \left\|P(A)^*P(A)\right\| = \left\|(\overline P P)(A)\right\|$$

Comment: Actually I just noticed that in the book that $P$ is a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N x^n$ for some finite $N$. Does this proof stll hold in this case?

Comment: @eurocoder Its even simpler in that case, no need to appeal to the continuity of $*$.