# C* Algebra textbook recommendation

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, c-star-algebras

I have read the first two chapters from Analysis Now and the chapter on C* algebras (chptr 8?).  I'm taking a course on C* algebras in the spring and am currently overwhelmed with the choices. I'd like to get something that isn't too highbrow. Any recommendations from experts or students in the field would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450132/reference-for-operator-algebra/450138#450138

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate..... I'm no expert, but I think its safe to say that the general theory of operator algebras is more encompassing than C* algebras, here I have 3 answers (and counting?), but on the other page only ONE answer with only C* algebra references (which is a lack of answers on that page, and is independent of my question).  There are several books in operator algebras that avoid the C* approach, right?

Comment: Based on my experience in learning $C^*$-algebra, I recommend Murphy's book. However, If you are looking for a self contained introduction to the subject, you may enjoy reading my lecture notes which is available at arxiv.

Comment: thanks.... I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

W. Arveson: *An Invitation to $C^*$-Algebras*, Springer (The presentation is as simple and concrete.)

G.J. Murphy: *$C^*$- Algebras and operator theory*. Academic Press. (Very accessible and
readable.)

K. Davidson: *$C^*$-algebras by example*. AMS. (Useful example-based approach.)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, I would also recommend :

1. Dixmier, *C$^{\ast}$ algebras* : It is old, and hard to come by, but really very informative. The treatment of Group C* algebras is particularly good (as it is in Ken Davidson's book)
2. R.G. Douglas, *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* : A second edition of this has recently come out. The book focusses on applications to the theory of Fredholm and Toeplitz operators, so it is useful if you want to do some operator theory.
3. Gelfand, Raikov and Shilov, *Commutative Normed Rings* : Another very old book, but it was the first book (that I came across) on the subject, and it is really very cool. It contains Gelfand's famous proof of [Weiner's theorem](http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/shk/public_html/wiener1.pdf)
4. Kadison and Ringrose, *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras* : It is a 4-volume book that covers everything. The first volume contains, for instance, a C* algebraic proof of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (which is due to De Branges, I believe).

Other somewhat more advanced books :

1. Takesaki, *Theory of Operator Algebras*
2. Pedersen, *C$^{\ast}$ algebras and their Automorphism Groups*

Answer (score 2):

I really like [C$^*$-Algebras by Example](http://books.google.com/books?id=0TXteNfrzvcC&printsec=frontcover&output=html_text). Very readable intro on my opinion.