# In which kinds of books can I find the definition of exponential operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have been studying real and functional analysis recently, but I hadn't encountered an exponential operator such as $e^{L}$ until I recently read a paper. In which kinds of books can I find the definition of this concept? Operator algebra or functional analysis or Lie algebra? I'd appreciate it if you'd help me. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450132/reference-for-operator-algebra

Comment: it depends on what is $L$ in your example. If $L$ is a linear operator then in books of linear algebra or books of functional analysis

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked it up in the books you recommended to me, but I cannot find the definition and the properties of $e^L$, even though there are lots of high-level contents in them. I really hope to find a proper explanation of it.

Comment: In the paper you are reading, what is $L$?  The answer definitely depends on the context.  If it's a linear operator, read a book on functional analysis.  If it's an element of a Lie algebra, a book on differential geometry would be more helpful.  I can give you recommendations for either, but I can give more detailed recommendations depending on the context.

Comment: @Aweygan Sorry I forgot to mention about $L$. $L$ is a linear operator, more specifically $L \colon = A^*A+B$, $B^*=-B$. (I've attached the photo of the book, sorry it was a book titled 'hypercoercivity', not a paper.), where $A:H \to H^n$, $B: H \to H$, unbounded operators and $H$ is a Hilbert space. 

I have a bunch of functional analysis books such as Conway, Brezis, Rudin, and P.Lax, but I coudn't find the proper definition and the properties of it. Also I don't know in which context it appears. I'd really appreciate it if you'd give me good references.

Comment: @Aweygan Actually I have books that introduce the exponentiation of matrices.

Comment: Well I don't have my library currently in front of me, and I'm not as educated in unbounded operators as I should be, but the general idea would probably be in the section on unbounded operators in either Conway or Rudin.  I'll come back to this later.

Comment: For practical applications, you might want to look for how the exponent of the momentum operator can effect translations of a wave function. Time evolution is also related to exponentiation of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Aweygan Thank you for responding to me. You don't have to be knowledgeable about unbounded operators. For me, it is enough to know what $e^L$ is for now. I'd appreciate it if you'd come back.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed Thanks for your advice, but it's too much... Sadly, I don't understand what you are talking about. (I want to understand it!)

Answer (score 1):

A. Pazy, "*Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations*".

This is one of the most readable books on the subject, and he starts with bounded operators and defines $e^{-tL}$ using an exponential series. He then works more general theories.

The original ideas for treating time solutions with an exponential came from the Electrical Engineer O. Heaviside. His ideas were highly original, controversial, and not well-understand. Heaviside's ideas eventually led to the development of the modern version of Laplace transform and its Bromwich integral inverse.

Heaviside introduced the idea of an evolution operator $S(t)$ that would take the state $x$ of an electrical system to its state $S(t)x$ after $t$ seconds. He reasoned that a time-independent circuit would have the property that $S(t')(S(t)x)=S(t+t')x$; that is, evolving $t$ seconds and then $t'$ more seconds would be the same as evolving $t+t'$ seconds. And $S(0)=I$ would hold because you're not doing anything to the system by evolving $0$ seconds.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much for your valuable recommendation! Finally, I got the proper book. :) Also, last night, I looked it up on the internet so hard and I ended up find something related to it, which is 'holomorphic functional calculus'. Do you think this is a different approach to it?

Comment: @withgrace1040 : The holomorphic functional calculus mainly deals with bounded operators, which requires that you have a bounded spectrum. There is a way to approach exponentiation for the generators of $C_0$ semigroups using this approach, but it is not as practical from a theoretical viewpoint, though it can be elegant when coupled with the Laplace transform. Pazy looks at several approaches, including the holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: @withgrace1040 The Laplace transform $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}S(t)x dt$ intuitively gives $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}e^{tA}xdt = \frac{1}{\lambda I-A}=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}x$. So you can use the inverse Laplace transform on the resolve operator $(\lambda I-A)^{-1}$ to obtain the exponential semigroup $S(t)$. Pazy also goes through that!

Comment: Thank you again! By the way, by saying that "Pazy also goes through that!", you mean only through the book "Semigroups of Linear Operators" or with his other books?

Comment: @withgrace1040 : Pazy also goes through the development using the Laplace and inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: Yes, you mean in the book you recommended to me titled  "Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations", right? :)

Comment: @withgrace1040 : Yes, the book I recommended by Pazy deals with this.

Comment: I am reading the book by Pazy, but I have some question on page 2, he says "Let $T(t)$ be a uniformly continuous semigroup of bounded linear operators
on $X$. Fix $\rho > 0$, small enough, such that $\Vert I - \rho^{-1} \int^{\rho}_{0} T(s) ds\Vert < 1 $". Here, what does $\int^{\rho}_{0} T(s) ds$ mean? I know a little about the vector-space function, but how can we show $T(t)$ is (strongly) measurable and also integrable? To me, $\Vert I - \rho^{-1} \int^{\rho}_{0} T(s) ds\Vert < 1 $ $(*)$ seems like the mean value thm in a Banach space, but I cannot show $(*)$. Can you give me any help?

Answer (score -1):

Some suggested linear algebra topics for research. Also leads to practical application in Quantum Mechanics.

A lot of the analysis is based off of common ways of building up these concepts from the basic arithmetic.

For example, $2^N$ for integer N means $2\cdot 2 \cdot2...\cdot 2$ for a list of N 2's in a row.

From this meaning you can find $2^M \cdot 2 ^N=2^{(M+N)}$. You can also work backwards by dividing by two an get $2^0=1$, $2^{-1}=1/2$, $2^{-2}=1/4$, and so on.

But don't think of this as division, but multiplying by the inverse, which is the formal, more fundamental definition of division.

From hear you can generalize to how the concepts apply to matrices.

Given invertible matrix M, we can multiply it by itself n times. You can multiply the identity matrix by the inverse of M to get negative exponents of M.

You can diagonalize matrices to facilitate understanding fractional powers of a matrix.

If $M=A^{-1}BA$, then in general, $M^p=A^{-1}B^pA$ even for fractional powers of p, for suitable M.

You can generalize using the Binomial theorem:

$(I+A)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p \ {p \choose k}A^k$, the general form allowing for fractional exponents.

A text on Real Analysis teaches that from the binomial theorem and its general form, you can map exponentiation with the argument as the independent variable to having the base  as the independent variable, i.e. $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/3!+...$ once you define limits as they apply to matrices.

In particular, $(1+a)^N=1+Na+...$ can be swapped with $(1+a/N)^N=1+a+...$. Take the limit as N goes to infinity and we get $e^a$.

By similar reasoning, for a matrix M, you have $e^M=I+M+M^2/2+M^3/3!+...$

In quantum mechanics you can let $M=-i\hbar\Delta x_0 \hat{D}$ where $\hat{D}$ is the differential operator, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in one dimension.

Plugging it in you get:

$e^M=I+(-i\hbar \Delta x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}/1!+(-i\hbar \Delta x_0)^2/2!\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+...$

So the exponential operator, which can be expressed as a matrix, is the sum of the powers of other Linear Operators. This operator being [The Translation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics))

Comment: You need to be careful about representing the exponential of an unbounded operator via power series. The whole theory of making sense of convergence of that sum requires a fairly strong bound which doesn't exist for unbounded operators.

Comment: The proofs for matrix exponential (or even exponentials of bounded operators on Banach spaces) doesn't carry over to the unbounded operator situation.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! Also, thank you for your answer, TurlocTheRed.